# HTML - How to add a box within a box with some text centered in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want it to look something like the image below

[image: Should look like this]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/JA7vh/

Answer (score 2):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tq8Ff/4/

Code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inner">new message form heaquarter</div>
</div>

.inner {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
 text-align:center;
 background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/a3U5a/